# How to upload a file in thread without interrupting other work?

Tags: java

i am uploading a file in thread by writting this code

```
import java.io.*;
public class FileUploadThread extends Thread {

    File f1, f2;
    String fileName;
    InputStream stream;
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];

    public FileUploadThread(File f1, File f2, InputStream stream, String filename) {
        System.out.println("external class file name--->" + filename);
        this.f1 = f1;
        this.f2 = f2;
        this.stream = stream;
        this.fileName = filename;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            f2 = new File(f1, fileName);
            OutputStream w = new FileOutputStream(f2);

            int res = stream.read(b);
            System.out.println("res = "+res);
            while (res >= 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < res; i++) {
                    w.write(b);
                }
              res = stream.read(b);
              System.out.println("res--->" + res);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("In the run method of the thread");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

It shows me `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Where exactly do you encounter the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds?

Comment: external class file name--->32420-F005-1-1001-2.TIF
res = 1024
res--->1024
res--->1024
res--->1024
res--->978
In the run method of the thread
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:416)

Comment: @user1671342 are you trying to run the upload file as separate process?

Comment: yes as a separator process from my servlet i have called this thread class

Comment: @User1671342 Make a functionupload() as differed thread it would execute as separate thread .using thread  class it would start as differen thread under the parent process

Comment: Actually i am taking from jsp page's browse field then after submit it goes to servlet with multipart request then in servlet i am calling the thread sothat with out any interruption process due to file uploading time my work will go smoothly and file uploading process will go through the thread with out any interruption in my other work in my web app

Comment: what happen guys no answer from anybody ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `w.write(b, 0, res)`

The method you are using essentially is calling `w.write(b, 0, b.length)`, but the read can return up to `b.length` bytes

**UPDATE**

Your copy loop should look more something like...

```
OutputStream w = null;
try {
    f2 = new File(f1, fileName);
    w = new FileOutputStream(f2);

    int res = -1;
    while ((res = stream.read(b)) != -1) {
        w.write(b, 0, res);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("In the run method of the thread");
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        w.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Don't forget, if you open a stream, you are responsible for closing it...

Comment: You need to get rid of the for loop and use the `w.write(b, 0, res)` variant as you only need to do it once.

Comment: still its showing the same error in netbeans output array index out of bounds exception and in browser it becoming white

Comment: @kal there's a earlier question today about why NOT to do that. While for small files I would agree, it's not worth the risk if you can't guarantee the file size of the life time of the app

Comment: so what should i do is it due to thread the exception coming?

Comment: No, the minor problem is the two loops.  You don't need them

Comment: sorry i havent written that in this code w.close() but i am using that one still its showing me the exception using only while loop also i have tried but still its shwoing me the problem

Comment: Can you post the actual exception

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:416)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:310)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:202)
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:976)
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.close(MultipartStream.java:923)
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.close(

Comment: In fact there's an Apache library (`commons-fileupload`) that has a `Streams` class with a `copy` static method for doing this :) Reading from an input-stream and writing everithing to an outputstream. At least it could be useful to read how they do it.

Comment: Actually i am taking from jsp page's browse field then after submit it goes to servlet with multipart request then in servlet i am calling the thread sothat with out any interruption process due to file uploading time my work will go smoothly and file uploading process will go through the thread with out any interruption in my other work in my web app

Comment: please suggest me something to do

Comment: Firstly, make sure the process works without threads. You may have an issue where when the servlet returns, the connections are been cleaned up under you...

Comment: what happen guys no answer from anybody ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your situation,but it just works fine for me. And i have two suggestions for this program:

1.Since you assign the f2 reference in the run function as `f2 = new File(f1, fileName);` ,why do you pass another File parameter `File f2` in the constructor? As far as i can see, the f2 parameter in the constructor is useless.

2.You don't need a for loop to write. Once you call `w.write(b)`,it actually flush all the bytes in b and then write to f2.

Comment: Actually i am taking from jsp page's browse field then after submit it goes to servlet with multipart request then in servlet i am calling the thread sothat with out any interruption process due to file uploading time my work will go smoothly and file uploading process will go through the thread with out any interruption in my other work in my web app

Comment: what happen guys no answer from anybody ?